# Fetching attachments with custom extension in my Android application

Tags: android, android-intent, view, intentfilter

What I am trying to achieve is sounds very familiar, it has been posted many times here and there in Stack Overflow as well, but I'm unable to get it done.

The scenario is, I receive a mail with attachment having custom extension in it. The extension is recognized by my app and it needs the FilePath to process it.

Currently, when I get the attachment in my app using `getIntent().getData()` all I get is path of the form `content://`

I have seen methods to convert media content of the type `content://` to FilePath like `/sdcard/file.ext` but I was unable to convert the attachment using that. May be its obvious.

Is there any way that I can process the `content://` type without actually downloading it.

Currently from the k9 mail app, when I get the custom extension, it shows my app in the list and opens it through it, but I need FilePath like `/sdcard/file.ext` and I'm only able to get `content://` type.

I hope I made the question clear.

Please Help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `content://` Uri does not necessarily point to a file on the sdcard.
It is more likely that it points to any kind of data stored in a database
or to a content provider that gives you access to the private file storage of another app.

I think the later one is the case with mail attachments (if the content provider is not requesting it directly from a web server). So converting the `content://` Uri to a path will not work.

I did the following (not sure if it works also for k9 mail app)

```
Uri uri = intent.getData();
if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
    String fileName = ContentProviderUtils.getAttachmentName(this, uri);
    if (fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".ext")) {
        InputStream is = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        // do something
    } else {
        // not correct extension
        return;
    }
} else if (uri.getScheme().equals("file")) {
    String path = uri.getPath();
    if (path.toLowerCase().endsWith(".ext")) {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);
        // do something
    } else {
        // not correct extension
        return;
    }
}
```

The attachment name can be found by

```
public static String getAttachmentName(Context ctxt, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = ctxt.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    String res = "";
    if (cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        res = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
        cursor.close();
    }

    return res; 
}
```

Comment: I used this method from another post, but your answer is correct, it is useful to others as well, hence marked it correct. But as I tried the above method, it turns out it does not work in every device. Hence changing `DISPLAY_NAME` to `_display_name` like suggested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035535/android-get-email-attachment-name-in-my-application) would be better and would work on more devices.