# How to get file name open from gmail app by intent?

Tags: android, android-file, android-fileprovider

While importing a file with custom Extention from the Gmail app to my app I am getting a cache(cache0) file name instead of exact file name(abc.test).

Is there any way to get the correct file name?

Comment: You did not show the code that gave you an incorrect file name.

Comment: It works [https://stackoverflow.com/a/6363712/10818600](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6363712/10818600)